# NA's not getting replaced

Tags: r, if-statement, missing-data

my data has lot of missing names so i decide to replace all NA's of name variable with "nameless" so i applied ifelse function but iam not getting the correct output

> full$Name<-ifelse(nchar(full$Name) == 0,"nameless",full$Name)

"nameless" is not repalcing the NA's                                               is am doing it right or should i do something else

Comment: You could have tried `nchar(NA)` as a straightforward debugging step. You would have realized that, surprisingly, this returns `2`. If you are concerned that NA is not a character, you can try `nchar(NA_character_)` which, somewhat even more surprisingly, returns `2` as well. Bottomline, you cannot test if a value is `NA` by using `nchar`. Use `is.na` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard subsetting, this should work:

```
full$Name[is.na(full$Name)] <- "nameless"
```